# Nested Weight In XML Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

Here's my layout,I get a warning saying: `"Nested weights are bad for performance"` for `ImageView`. How can I avoid this and what am I doing wrong?

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/white">


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1.50">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/left_top"
        android:layout_weight=".75"  
        android:contentDescription="@string/title" 
        />
     <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.25"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title" 
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/right_top" 
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title"  />

</LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagefirstname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        />


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/welcome_title"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
         /> 

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight=".75">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/left_bottom"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title" 
        />
     <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.25"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title" 
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/right_bottom" 
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title"  />

</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective? Maybe this question too basic, but i did't find any suitable solution.

Please Help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636323/nested-weights-are-bad-for-performance-in-my-xml-code

Comment: @vjdhama Both are different . Its not duplicate .Before asking this question i have checked this link .Hope you understand my voice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Android docs :

> Using nested instances of LinearLayout can lead to an excessively deep
>   view hierarchy. Nesting several instances of LinearLayout that use the
>   layout_weight parameter can be especially expensive as each child
>   needs to be measured twice. This is particularly important when the
>   layout is inflated repeatedly, such as when used in a ListView or
>   GridView.

Further
`The performance might improve by flattening the layout—make the layout shallow and wide, rather than narrow and deep.`

You have one `LinearLayout` inside another with layout weights. Rather than that you could use `RelativeLayout` in place of `LinearLayout`.

Have a good read of [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) for more information.