# Android five horizontal imageviews

Tags: android

I want to have 5 imageviews, one next to each other (horizontally) and each imageview should have the width of 1/5 the screen. Instead of measuring and setting widths inside the activity, I achieved the result using linear layouts this way:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.davidbalas.brawlstarsinfo.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontName="supercell.ttf" />


        <com.davidbalas.brawlstarsinfo.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontName="supercell.ttf" />

        <com.davidbalas.brawlstarsinfo.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/top5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/top_5_brawlers_for"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontName="supercell.ttf" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/top_5_brawlers_for"
                android:src="@drawable/barley" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/top_5_brawlers_for"
                android:src="@drawable/barley" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/top_5_brawlers_for"
                android:src="@drawable/barley" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/top_5_brawlers_for"
                android:src="@drawable/barley" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/top_5_brawlers_for"
                android:src="@drawable/barley" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

However, I get an error nested weights are bad for performance. What is a good, other way, to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Maybe constrait-layout

Comment: Refer this Link . You will get understand[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636323/nested-weights-are-bad-for-performance-in-my-xml-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636323/nested-weights-are-bad-for-performance-in-my-xml-code)

Comment: yes, you can ignore to check that warning, and use weight_sum in your layout

Comment: @Suresh I don't really like the solution of ignoring the error, is a tablelayout with 1 row better?

Comment: @RanjanDas Please see above.

Comment: Apparently you can use a TableRow without a TableLayout, thanks, problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem this way;

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />
     <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />
     <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />
     <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />
     <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />


 </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```